# How to use both Java and Groovy syntax when working with arrays?

Tags: java, groovy

Hypothetical question from a fresh Groovy wanderer/learner:

If there are differences between initializing arrays as stated [in official Groovy page, 3. Array initializers](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html)

> In Groovy, the `{ …​ }` block is reserved for closures.  That means that
>   you cannot create array literals with this syntax:
>
> ```
> int[] array = { 1, 2, 3}
> ```
>
> You actually have to use:
>
> ```
> int[] array = [1,2,3]
> ```

How can we use both Java and Groovy syntax initializing array at the same class? Wouldn't compiler report errors at compile time? If not - why would it compile code?

Comment: *How can we use both Java and Groovy syntax initializing array at the same class?* - It's not both groovy and java, it's groovy. It may be similar to java sometimes, but it's still groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix up the array initialization syntax between languages.

A class is defined in either `.groovy` or `.java` source file. A source file can't be compiled by both Groovy and Java compiler at the same time. Because of that you can't use the Java syntax in `.groovy` source file and Groovy syntax in `.java` source file.

Comment: Basically only good thing is using same JVM runtime environement? I can use objects of Java classes in Groovy code and vice versa, right?

Comment: Yes, although it's much easier to use Java object in Groovy code than the other way around.

Comment: @Miki Also `groovyc` can work with both `.java` and `.groovy` source files (it delegates to `javac` for the first).  That allows for easy mixing of code bases and prevent circular dependency problems.  So you can at least mix and match at the _file_ level.